# Execute maven plugin goal jetty:run on Intellij error: "Permission denied"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm developing a multi-module maven project. I'd like to develop that project on Ubuntu environment with IntelliJ. 
When I execute maven goal "jetty:run" with Intellij maven plugin, the console give me error information "permission denied" and Fail.

2011-12-16 16:55:46.371::INFO:  jetty-6.1.15
2011-12-16 16:55:46.588::INFO:  No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2011-12-16 16:55:48.684:/:INFO:  Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'flamingo'
2011-12-16 16:55:50,068 INFO [com.jje.flamingo.extend.JPropertiesConfigurer] - Loading properties file from class path resource [domain.properties]
2011-12-16 16:55:52.912::WARN:  failed SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:80
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty is configured to use port 80, which is not allowed if you are not running as root. Try to change the port to something above 1024 in the configuration.

Comment: What if you want to use port 80? how do you run as root>

Comment: @JaKXz you have to run the IDE as root or install some reverse proxy server like nginx that will run as root on port 80 and forward the requests to your server.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am using IntelliJ 12 on OS X Mavericks. Will a `sudo "/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app/Contents/MacOS/idea"` do the trick?

Comment: Should work. You can also try `sudo open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app`.